# Scala - pattern-matching a tuple of related types

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, tuples

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends A
```

then, there is another class which takes instances of these classes and there is a method, in which two cases of pattern-matching are possible like this:

```
class D (one: A, two: A) {

  def work {
    (one, two) match {
      case (o, t): (B, B) => ... blablabla
      case (o, t): (B, C) => ... blablabla
      case _ =>
    }
  }
}
```

However, when it should resolve the matching in favor of the second case `(B, C)`, it tries resolving it as `(B, B)` and comes up with the class cast exception that `C cannot be cast to B`. Why? What to do? How can I come around this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your syntax isn't quite right (doesn't compile).

This works though:

```
object Matcher extends App {

  class A
  class B extends A
  class C extends A

  class D(one: A, two: A) {

    def work {
      (one, two) match {
        case (o: B, t: B) => println("B")
        case (o: B, t: C) => println("C")
        case _ =>
      }
    }
  }

  val d1 = new D(new B, new B)
  val d2 = new D(new B, new C)

  d1.work
  //B
  d2.work
  //C
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem, as always, is erased types. `(B,C)` is syntactic sugar for `Tuple2[B,C]`, which is erased to `Tuple2` at runtime. The case statement verifies that `(B,C)` matches `Tuple2`, but then fails to cast it.

In your case, the easiest solution would be to match against 'one' and 'two' individually, rather than wrapping them in a tuple:

```
one match {
  case o : B => two match {
    case p : C => ...
    case p : B => ...
  }
  ... 
}
```

It's not so pretty, but it won't suffer from the same problems.

Edit: Actually, I'd go with Brian Smith's solution - matching inside the tuple rather than outside. It avoids the problem in a similar way, but looks nicer.

Answer (score 3):

I made this code work.

Firstly I added a case to your class definition.

```
case class A
case class B extends A
case class C extends A
```

Secondly I changed the `work`.

```
class D(one: A, two: A) {
  def work {
    (one, two) match {
      case (o: B, t: B) => println("BB")
      case (o: B, t: C) => println("BC")
      case (o: C, t: C) => println("CC")
      case _ => println("AA")
    }
  }
}
```

Now what I got:

```
new D(B(),B()).work      => BB
new D(B(),C()).work      => BC
new D(C(),C()).work      => CC
new D(A(),B()).work      => AA
```

The `case` adds an apply and an unapply method.

Comment: Yeah, case classes... but they have bugs with inheritance.. I will be very happy if they fix that sometime...

Comment: This code won't compile in modern Scala, because case inheritance is prohibited since 2.9 I think. @noncom This is not a bug, this is by design

Comment: @NikitaVolkov I copied this code from the REPL (Scala 2.9.1). It did compile.

Comment: @T.Grottker Not without warnings I'm sure. In Scala 2.10 it doesn't compile

Comment: @NikitaVolkov no, actually I remember quite well them telling that implementing proper inheritance is very hard due to technical problems with compiler and JVM or something like that and the contemporal implementation contained bugs, i.e. "use at your own risk - it may work or it may break". Idk which way the things went next, maybe they've explicitly prohibited such inheritance.. because I have dropped Scala some years ago and went totally Clojure.